# How to get diagrams like this?

Tags: tikz-trees

How to make diagrams like this with tikz?

[image: Diagrams like this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you could do it for *ad hoc* diagrams:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={circle, draw}, >=Stealth]
\node (A) at (0,0) {};
\node (B) [below of=A] {};
\node (C) [below of=B] {};
\node (D) [left of=A] {};
\node (E) [right of=A] {};
\draw[->] (A) -- (B);
\draw[->] (B) -- (C);
\draw[->] (D) -- (B);
\draw[->] (E) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

For larger trees I'd recommend looking for a suitable package on CTAN, e.g. `forest`.

Comment: is it `below of=` or `below=of`

Comment: Good question! I've always used `below of` etc., but looking at the TikZ/pgf manual now (section 17.5, _Positioning Nodes_), it looks like `below=of A` should be correct. Given that I'm actually surprised TikZ never complained about the way I've been doing it.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={circle,draw},my/.style={draw,latex-}, 
    edge from parent/.style={my}]
\path node (b) {} [grow'=up]
    child {node {}
      child {node {}}
      child {node {}}
      child {node (r) {}  edge from parent[draw=none]}
    } (b) edge[my] (r) 
  (5,0) node (b') {} [grow'=up]
    child {node {}
      child {node (r') {}  edge from parent[draw=none]}
      child {node {}}
      child {node {}}
    } (b') edge[my] (r') ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]